# Pass defined value as pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Hello I have small problem with followed C code:

```
 //Hardcoded commands:

 #define someCommand 0x1223;
 #(...)

 //functions definitions:
 void socketWrite(uint8_t address, const uint8_t *data, size_t length);

 //main task
 int main(){

 //I want send someCommand to socket
 socketWrite(0xff, &someCommand, 1);

 (...)
 }
```

this code give me of course compilation error:
error: 'someCommand' was not declared in this scope

but my question is about how write this correctly without creating new buffer data that can handle this command like this:

```
uint8_t * buff;
*buff = someCommand;
socketWrite(0xff, buff, 1);
```

Comment: Why don't you use a plain `int` constant rather than that `#define`?

Comment: defines are outside of my code and there are a lot of (I think 2k) If I create 2k const int gnu linked all of they to my memory or only that i use in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`someCommand` is a #define. The C preprocessor generates a source text by replacing it by its value.
So your code looks like:

```
socketWrite( 0xff, &0x1223, 1 );
```

Taking address of 0x1223 isn't possible.

```
int value = someCommand;
socketWrite( 0xff, &value, 1 );
```

may works

otherwise:

```
const int someCommand = 0x1223;
```

and later

```
socketWrite(0xff, &someCommand, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using C99's brace initializers (probably not the right name)

```
socketWrite(0xff, &(uint8_t) { someCommand }, 1);
```

This is essentially the same as making a temp variable equal to `someCommand` and getting the address of it.

Comment: looks great but give me an error: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

Comment: @MazerytFreager interesting. According to the standard, this is legal code. What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

## define someCommand 0x1223;

You must avoid the ';' semicolon in the macro definition.